# cannot remove jpg using unlink function

Tags: php

**Delete Function**

```
function delete_news($id,$img)
{
    $sql = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM `nm_news` WHERE news_id=:id");
    $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $sql->execute();
    unlink("uploads/".$img);
    header('Location: all_news.php');
    $this->con = null;
}
```

Here I am able to delete all image like jpeg and png but unable to delete jpg

**Inserting Image function**

```
function update_category($id, $category_title, $sort_order, $status)
{
    $target_dir    = "uploads/";
    $target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk      = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    }
    $image = basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"], ".jpg");
    if ($image) {
        $sql = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE nm_category SET category_title=:category_title,category_image=:category_image,category_order=:category_order,category_status=:category_status  WHERE category_id=:id");
        $sql->bindParam(':category_title', $category_title);
        $sql->bindParam(':category_image', $image);
        $sql->bindParam(':category_order', $sort_order);
        $sql->bindParam(':category_status', $status);
        $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
    }
}
```

Insertion of image is working fine, but unlink on jpg is not working only working on jpeg and png

***Result o/p:*** after pressing delete button, the whole data gets deleted but the image still remains in the folder of uploads

Comment: Error message? Warning? Anything in the logs? Is that the right relative path?

Comment: "unlink isn't working" doesn't meaningfully describe a problem.  What is the exact path of the file?  What are the runtime values you're passing to `unlink`?  What is the result?

Comment: no error or warning is  been shown, and path is proper

Comment: shortly described: unlink does not removes jpg files from upload folder

Comment: first of all `$sql->execute();unlink("uploads/".$img);` needs to be `if($sql->execute()){ unlink("uploads/".$img);}` . And please add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top of your php file where you created delete function

Comment: sorry i am begineer pls do not downvote for this mistakes

Comment: I am astonished that same code removed `jpeg` and `png`  but not `jpg`. what magic happening with `jpg`?

Comment: alive to die error reporting is ON

Comment: @dhruv  try to provide full path inside `unlink()` and check it worked or not?

Comment: @dhruv: The downvotes aren't for beginner mistakes.  The downvotes are because you're not providing any debugging information and are simply insisting that we should trust that your code is correct and that you're doing everything right and that `unlink` itself must be broken.  That's not a problem we can help with.  It's *far more likely* that you're making a mistake somewhere and that your values aren't what you expect them to be.  But as long as you refuse to examine those values, we can't help.

Comment: tried full path not working

Comment: agreed with @David

Comment: but can't u see unlink() working on jpeg and png but jpg so there might be something problem with jpg files that is out of my knowledge that i can recieve here

Comment: jpg is not a magical file extension. your code have some issue somewhere.

Comment: `$image = basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"], ".jpg");` You're storing the `basename` of the image in your db, without the extension `.jpg` if it has one. For `.jpeg` and `.png` files it looks like you store the `basename` _including_ the file extension in your db which is why you can unlink them

Comment: @dhruv: No, we can't see that.  We can't see inside your computer or debug your code for you from here.  This is, however, a great opportunity for you to familiarize yourself with some basic PHP debugging.  Now is the time to validate all of the runtime values and behaviors of your code.  Go to your file system and find the exact and complete path and name of the file you are expecting to delete.  Then in your code when you are trying to delete the file, output or log the exact and complete path and name you're using.  Are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$image = basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"], ".jpg");` to `$image = basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);`

This was only storing the complete filename including extension for `.jpeg` and `.png` files. When you uploaded a `.jpg` file you stored the file in your `uploads/` folder *including* the extension but saving to database *without* the extension.

So for example `myJpgFile.jpg` exists in your `uploads/` folder, but you were trying to unlink `myJpgFile` from your `uploads/` folder - which doesn't exist.